# javascript object returns length 0 even when object is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to add multiple markers to google map.

My code :

```
function createMarkers(myArray) {
       var myOptions = {
        zoom:6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.704059, 77.102490)
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      //shows the object in console with length of 3
      console.log(myArray);

      //but here length return is 0 so no Entry on FOR Loop
      console.log(myArray.length);


    for(var x=0;x<myArray.length;x++){

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myArray[i],
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }

}

function initialize(){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var cityArray   =   ['Agra','Delhi','Varanasi'];

      var myLatLng =    [];

     for(var i=0;i<cityArray.length;i++){

      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': cityArray[i]+', India'
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var Lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          myLatLng.push({'lat': Lat, 'lng': Lng});


        } else {
          alert("Something got wrong " + status);
        }
    });
    }

  //console.log(myLatLng);
  createMarkers(myLatLng);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

<style>
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
</style>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

I got latitute and logitude in array of objects. Now i want to iterate over this in the createMarkers(myLatLng) function. But in this function i am able to log this object to console and showing length of 3 . But when want to get its length for looping it always return 0;

Comment: When you execute createMarkers(myLatLng); , the array is not populated. It's an asynchronous operation, the array is filled when the *callbacks* of the geocode() method are executed.

Comment: thanks i solved it..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your problem is with async callback.

when JS preforms "async" actions (like jQuery `ajax` and `geocoder.geocode`) the action takes some time but the code below this request is executed without waiting.

that's why `geocoder.geocode` has that function inside it that checks if it was successful, this one:

```
   function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var Lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      myLatLng.push({'lat': Lat, 'lng': Lng});

      createMarkers(myLatLng); // THIS IS A NEW LINE

    } else {
      alert("Something got wrong " + status);
    }
```

that only executes **after** your call was completed.
just pass `createMarkers(myLatLng);` inside that [`callback function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and it should work as planned.

Comment: thank you mystery downvoter! any special reason? was my answer not correct? did I not link to resource? was it not helpful and explanatory? teach me so I can do better in your eyes in the future